# IntelliJ IDEA: two-finger touchpad scrolling does not work

Tags: xorg, touchpad, scrolling, ideapad, intellij

I think this is a known issue since I see it on different laptops, but still does not google easily.

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I unplug mouse and use my (synaptics?) Lenovo touchpad under Linux, it won't scroll. Period. It won't vertical scroll in the source window, which is a killer.

Is there a way to make IDEA scroll under Linux/X11 when using touchpad, specifically the Lenovo kind? I currently use 21.04 but I saw this previously on 20.04 and perhaps before that.

Comment: I am having this issue now on Ubuntu 20.04. Have you found a solution? I am able to "2 finger touchpad scroll" in chrome etc... but not in PHP storm. Thank you,

Comment: No, I have not, and it's weird that there's so few attention to this issue.